# How can I style a pandas dataframe in Python with input upper and lower tolerance levels for conditional formatting?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, apply

I have a dataframe that I would like to export to an Excel file with some background styling for each column. Since each column has its own upper and lower bound to check for the conditional formatting.

I have tried to do it like this.

```
for count, value in enumerate(headers):
    df.style.apply(Back_color, upper_Tol[count], lower_Tol[count], subset = value)

def Back_color(col, upper, lower):
    # empty property list to be filled in the loop
    props = ['font-weight: bold;'] * len(col)
    for idx, value in enumerate(col):
        # color max value lightgreen
        if lower < value < upper:
            props[idx] += 'background-color: lightgreen;'
        # color min value lightcoral
        elif value < lower or value > upper:
            props[idx] += 'background-color: lightcoral'
        else:
            props[idx] += 'background-color: white'
    return props
```

with the start of the loop it immediately gives the error:
TypeError: apply() got multiple values for argument 'subset'

which is unclear to me why since I am only parsing a <class 'str'> as argument

could someone help me to solve this problem?. as I am also quite unfamiliar with the styling it might be that the definition is written wrong but i did not come that far for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use :

```
lower_Tol, upper_Tol = [0, 6, 0], [5, 9, 3]

def back_color(col, upper, lower):
    return [
        "background-color: lightgreen;font-weight: bold" if l < v < u
        else "background-color: lightcoral;font-weight: bold"
            for (v, u, l) in zip(col, upper, lower)
    ]

s = df.style.apply(back_color, upper=upper_Tol, lower=lower_Tol, axis=1)

#s.to_excel("ouput.xlsx", index=False) # uncomment this line to make a spreadsheet
```

Output :

[image]

*Input used :*

```
np.random.seed(1)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 9, size=(5, 3)),
                  columns=["column1", "column2", "column3"])
```

Comment: super thanks for the help man. for all the people that are working with this. it only works if all the cells are numerical. one can change non-numerical cells to numerical by: df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') this brute forces to become numerical. if new colums are added you can work with it by having a subset in the styling s = df.style.apply(back_color, upper=upper_Tol, lower=lower_Tol, axis=1, subset=headers) herein headers is the initial dataframe headers without the additions. this might be handy if you for instance want to add a datetime format or a column of strings

Comment: You're welcome ;) Glad it helped and thanks for the complement.